# how to sequence parameters in javascript functions

Tags: javascript

I was writing a code in javascript.

```
colorMixer = function (redIntensity, blueIntensity, greenIntensity)

{
   // mix color
}

colorMixer(10, 8, 7) // means red = 10, blue = 8, green = 7

colorMixer(10, 8) // means red = 10, blue = 8
```

Question: How to specify `red = 10, green = 8`, and no value for `blue` (i dont intend 0 value for blue) I want scene where value for blue is unknown and DONT want to provide any value for blue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing the calling method or function definition, you can use undefined.

```
colorMixer(10, undefined, 8);
```

And, then test each parameter to see if it's `undefined` within the function to see if it was passed.  You could also use `null` as the indicator that the parameter was not passed, but I prefer `undefined` because then you can just leave off trailing arguments you don't intend to pass and they will automatically be `undefined`.

But, if this is a regular occurence, you can change the parameters so they are passed in an object and the function can then examine exactly what was passed.  This is more extensible because it works equally well no matter how many possible arguments there are:

```
colorMixer({red: 10, blue: 8});
```

Then, in the colorMixer function itself, you look at the properties on the passed object and you can see exactly what was and wasn't passed.

Answer (score 2):

```
colorMixer(color) {
    var r = r in color ? color.r : DEFAULT_R,
        g = g in color ? color.g : DEFAULT_G,
        b = b in color ? color.b : DEFAULT_B;
}

colorMixer({r: 255, g: 127, b: 0});
colorMixer({g: 127, b: 0});
colorMixer({r: 255});
```

Edit actually what i wrote before my edit was wrong. If using a 0 for a channel, the default value would have been used as 0 evaluates to false.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `null` to the function.

```
colorMixer(10, null, 8);
```

Inside the function, you can check if null was passed.

```
colorMixer = function (redIntensity, blueIntensity, greenIntensity) {
    if (blueIntensity === null) { ... }
}
```

Note that the difference between `==` and `===` is important here.

`x == null` will also be true if a parameter wasn't passed, e.g., `colorMixer(1, 2)`

`x === null` requires that the value is `null`.

Comment: When last argument(s) of function is/are not passed `typeof lastArgument === undefined` so it would be better if you passed `undefined` instead of `null`.

Comment: Expecting null lets you differentiate with `===` if there's a need for it.  It's also easier to type.  If you want to check for null or undefined you can check with `x == null`, as I mentioned.  `typeof` isn't needed here, because arguments are always declared.

Comment: actually a loose comparaison `== null` allows to test both `=== null` and `=== undefined`

Comment: Well, all I was saying is that javascript handles optional parameters differently and while OP wants optional parameter, I'd treat it as javascript treats one to avoid _potential_ unexpected behavior. Nothing wrong with `null`.